# Tensorflow Object detection api example does not work for Tensorflow 1x

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

this is my first ML project, so I may be making a mistake in understanding.
I have trained a custom model using the tutorial [Tensorflow Object Detection API Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/README.md).
I am getting confused as this page says that currently object detection api does not support Tensorflow 2.x. However, when I read the [demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) 
it asks to install Tensorflow 2.x.

I don't understand when object detection api does not support tensorflow v2.x, why the demo asks to install tensorflow v2.x? Can you guys please help me understand this? I must be missing something.

Edit 1:
When I try to run the demo script using Tensorflow 1.15, I get below error

```
File "object_detection_custom.py", line 71, in run_inference_for_single_image
    num_detections = int(output_dict.pop('num_detections'))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tensor'
```

Edit 2:
Below is the output from model call

```
{
    u 'detection_boxes': < tf.Tensor 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0' shape = ( ? , 100, 4) dtype = float32 > , 
    u 'detection_classes': < tf.Tensor 'StatefulPartitionedCall:1' shape = ( ? , 100) dtype = float32 > , 
    u 'raw_detection_scores': < tf.Tensor 'StatefulPartitionedCall:6' shape = ( ? , ? , 2) dtype = float32 > , 
    u 'detection_scores': < tf.Tensor 'StatefulPartitionedCall:3' shape = ( ? , 100) dtype = float32 > , 
    u 'detection_multiclass_scores': < tf.Tensor 'StatefulPartitionedCall:2' shape = ( ? , 100, 2) dtype = float32 > , 
    u 'num_detections': < tf.Tensor 'StatefulPartitionedCall:4' shape = ( ? , ) dtype = float32 > , 
    u 'raw_detection_boxes': < tf.Tensor 'StatefulPartitionedCall:5' shape = ( ? , ? , 4) dtype = float32 >
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The demo link you referenced above is broken, but the notebook you refer to has [moved](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb).  This tutorial indeed uses TensorFlow 2, but only for inference.  Training requires TensorFlow 1.15.